# Reading file in Java (IDE used)

Tags: java, java-io

I was trying to write a piece of Java code to read each line from a file and add it to an Arraylist. Here is my code:

```
// try catch block removed for clarity.
file = new TextFileIn("names.txt");
String line = null;
while ((line = file.readLine()) != null) {
    list.add(line);
}
```

`names.txt` was located in the same package folder as my code. The IDE I used was Eclipse. When I run the code however I got a `FileNotFoundException`. The `TextFileIn` class comes from http://www.javaranch.com/doc/com/javaranch/common/TextFileIn.html

How could I get the file to be found?

Comment: Have you tried using the full path of "names.txt"? If this is an acceptable workaround, it should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're relying on the current working directory when accessing the file. The working directory depends on how you started the application. In Eclipse it's usually the project root folder. In commandline it's the currently opened directory. You cannot control this from inside the Java code, so this is considered a poor practice for files which are supposed to be part of the application itself.

The file is apparently in the same package as the running code, thus it's already in the classpath and then you could (and should) just get it straight from the classpath.

```
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("names.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
String line = null;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // ...
}
```

If you're calling this in `static` context, then replace `getClass()` by `YourClassName.class` where `YourClassName` is the name of the class where this code is sitting in.

#### See also:

- [`getResourceAsStream()` vs `FileInputStream`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream)

Answer (score 1):

It is located in the package folder. 
"names.txt" is referencing to the project root. So you have to search in your source folder like "src/your.package/names.txt".

Answer (score 0):

You should lern how to compile and run programs from the command line, and later, how to change the settings of your IDE, to do the same. The basic knowledge is something you can carry with you from IDE to IDE, from eclipse to netbeans, to IntelliJ... .

Even if you're running from the desktop by clicking or from an IDE, you're sitting virtually in a folder of your OS. In eclipse, it is by default your classes-dir when running the code, but can be modified in one of the `run as` tabs, and it is ${PROJECT}/bin or ${PROJECT}/classes, wherever your classes go. So you have to place your file there, but attention - it might get deleted if you press 'clean all' or something, so use a copy.

Instead of funny TextFileIn, why don't you use java.util.Scanner?

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner ("names.txt");
while (scanner.hasNextLine ())
    String line = scanner.nextLine ();
```

Comment: I was following the exercises on java ranch cattle drive, and it's the question requirement is that I use TextFileIn, in case you are curious :).

Comment: I know JavaRanch, but a link to that tutorial would be fine. Scanner isn't the youngest kid in town - in former times (1.4) it was a bit of a hassle to work with files: Wrapper around wrapper around wrapper - `r = new BufferedFileReader (new InputStreamReader (new LineInputStream (new File (name)))))));` or something like that. So a lot of teachers made a more easy to use class, and now their material spreads and spreads, and isn'T updated to the new Scanner.class, which is part of the JDK/JRE. Maybe the ranch should update their page?